# ExtJS: Grid Filtering in 4.2.1 (Upgrade Breakage)

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I have a grid filtering setup that works fine in ExtJS 4.1.1.1, but when I attempt to upgrade to 4.2.1.883, my grid filters no longer work, and I'm complete stumped as to why.  I'd like to upgrade because 4.2.x is notably faster for us. I'm using an MVC setup, and attempting to access the grid's filters programattically. Perhaps someone here can help! Here's what I've got:

```
// The Filters
var listFilters = {
  ftype: 'filters',
  autoReload: true,
  local: false,
  encode: 'encode',
  updateBuffer: 750,
  filters: [
    { type: 'numeric', dataIndex: 'id' },
    { type: 'string', dataIndex: 'title' }
  ]
};

// The Columns
var listColumns = [
  {
    id: 'id',
    text: 'ID',
    dataIndex: 'id',
    width: 150,
    filterable: true,
    filter: { type: 'numeric' }
  },
  {
    id: 'title',
    text: 'Title',
    dataIndex: 'title',
    width: 75,
    filterable: true,
    filter: { type: 'string' }
  }
];

// The Grid
Ext.define('JP.view.asset.List', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.assetlist',
  id: 'grid',
  store: 'Assets',              // referenced from another js file, per MVC
  layout: 'fit',
  features: [ listFilters ],    // filters referenced here
  columns: listColumns,         // columns referenced here
  listeners: {
    afterrender: function(grid) {
      // This works in 4.1.1, does nothing in 4.2.1
      grid.filters.createFilters();
      // ^^ Cannot call method 'createFilters' of undefined
      // :( :(
      // Can no longer reference `grid.filters` externally either, e.g.,
      // from Ext.tree
    }
  }
});
```

Any ideas?! I'm completely stumped here.  grid.filters can no longer be accessed programatically, nor do they load up in the GUI anymore (from column drop-downs). Works fine in 4.1.x.

Of course, I've loaded up the proper paths and so on...

```
// Load Ext.js MVC Application
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true,
  paths: { 'Ext.ux': 'javascript/ext-4.2.1/examples/ux' }
});

Ext.require([
  'Ext.grid.*',
  'Ext.data.*',
  'Ext.tree.*',
  'Ext.ux.*',
  'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'
]);
```

No such luck. It's as if the `ftype: 'filters'` is being ignored by the grid's `features` parameter altogether.

Thank you!!!

Comment: check to make sure the grid filter files are on the path and that the path is correct

Comment: Thanks for the input. My paths are correct (if I comment them out, things break, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the relevant snippet from an app in our 4.2 environment.

```
Ext.application({
    ...
    , paths: {'Ext.ux': '../[Path to ext]/src/ux/' }
    , requires: [
        'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'
    ]
    ...
});
```

Filters work like a charm.

Comment: Okay, I got these variables loaded up using `Ext.application` instead of `Ext.Loader.setConfig()`. Unfortunately, same results: everything _except_ the filters load up and work. Filters are just _ignored_. I'm baffled.

Comment: And to verify, looking around it Chrome's developer tools shows me that `FiltersFeature.js` and it's dependencies are indeed being successfully requested by the browser. So the scripts are loaded, it's just the grid isn't having the filters feature loaded for some reason. :(

Comment: It looks like `createFilters()` is a private method in 4.2.1 (don't have 4.1 available to reference). In your `afterrender` function try to `console.log(grid)` and validate the filters object exists.  you may not need to call the `createFilters()` method yourself, we don't.

Comment: I just added your listener to a grid with filters, and while it doesn't throw any errors, it actually prevents the filter from loading. Give that a try and see if it helps.

Comment: Okay, it was a combination of factors. I took your advice and removed `createFilters()`, moved my `paths` property out of `Ext.Loader.setConfig()` to `Ext.application`, and commented out a javascript file include that someone had left in our HTML header. Between those three things, everything works!!!!! Wooooo!!! Thank you very much Ken (and Oğuz and dbrin as well). Very awesome!

Comment: is there a way to minify these files and have a single js file like ext-all.js?

Answer (score 1):

The path should be `resources/ux` or if you want to use the file that is available in examples directory then use this `examples/ux/grid`